# In Scrum, what is an impediment?

Tags: scrum

One of the questions in Scrum is What impediments have you encountered? But what exactly is an impediment? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Dup of http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/5950/what-is-an-impediment-and-how-to-handle-them-and-internal-improvments-in-scrum?

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to the third question in a [**Daily Scrum**](http://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#events-daily) meeting:

> Do I see any impediment that prevents me or the Development Team from meeting the Sprint Goal?

This meeting is all about synchronizing the team's work towards reaching the **Sprint Goal**.  Think about it: The Team *works together* to reach the goal.  An impediment is *anything* that *could prevent* the Team from reaching the goal, and it is very important to identify those early, and take actions if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Somethat that prevents you from doing the a task that you should be working on. Some examples: Broken computer. Don't have the (x) from (y) that I need.

http://scrummethodology.com/scrum-impediments/